# Rails action shows it redirects but it does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect, render

I have a template in Rails where I use ajax to submit some params to an action in my controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subscribe-form").on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $('#subscribe-form')
                if (!$(form).valid()) {
                    return false;
                }
                showProcessing();
                client.tokenizeCard({
                    number: $('input[card-info=number]').val(),
                    expirationDate: $('select[card-info=expiry_month]').val()+ "/" + $('select[card-info=expiry_year]').val(),
                    cvv : $('input[card-info=cvv]').val() 
     },function (err, nonce) {
                    console.log(nonce);

                    hideProcessing()
                   if(err){
                     $(".alert-danger").show().text("Couldn't process your card");
                     hideProcessing();
                     return;
                   }
                    console.log(nonce);

                   if ($("input[name='braintreeToken']").length == 1) {
                      $("input[name='braintreeToken']").val(nonce);
                   } else {
                      form.append("<input type='hidden' name='braintreeToken' value='" + nonce + "' />");
                   }
                    console.log(nonce);

                   var options = {
                      success: subscribeResponseHandler, 
                      complete:  hideProcessing,
                      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      //url: 'http/localhost:3000/subscription/create'
                   };
                   $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
    });
               return false;
            });
        });
    </script>`
```

This is how I submit the params to my "action" method in my "subscription"controller.

```
`                    <form  action="/subscription/create" method="post" id="subscribe-form">
```

This gets into my create action.
There I have this line of code

```
 if true then
    File.open("letssee.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write("eftase edw" )}

    customer.update(has_plan: true)
    respond_to do |format|

       format.html { redirect_to(new_professional_session_path, :notice => 'Feedback was successfully updated.') }
       format.js
    end

    #this also does not work
    #redirect_to(new_professional_session_path, format: :html)
  return
else 
        File.open("letssee.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write("den eftase" )}

  redirect_to :action=>'new'
  return
end
```

In my terminal it says that the professional/sing_in is getting render.
It says it has succesfully redirected there.
Of course this route is bind to this path helper "new_professional_session_path".
But it DOES NOT changing page..
It says it gets redirected but it doesn't..

Sometikes I also get a missing template error, though the template exist.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
If I put this on the top,
  respond_to :html, :js

I get 
ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template subscription/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}.

Comment: Please clarify the controller file names. It's hard to figure out what's going on without knowing where you're redirecting from and to. Also, it should never look for a template called `create` because your application should not be making a `get` request to that route.

Comment: whats yr `subscribeResponseHandler ` in ajax form ?

Comment: My controller is called subscription. Inside it there are the new and the crate actions.
Inside the new template I make the Ajax call and send params to create action.
Then I want to redirect from create action to /professional/sign_in path (new_professional_session_path).

This is the sebscriberesponsehandler,
function subscribeResponseHandler(response) {
                    window.location.href = response.forward;
                     
   
                }

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting an async request via jQuery(processed as type js) and hence CAN NOT redirect within your controller.

What you can do however, is to redirect in your js response view:

```
window.location= '<%= new_professional_session_path %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending it as JSON, and your controller tries to answer as JSON.

**Controller:**

```
respond_to do |format|

   format.html { redirect_to(new_professional_session_path, :notice => 'Feedback was successfully updated.') }

   #add this one here
   format.json { render status: 200, json: new_professional_session_path }

   format.js
end
```

**$Ajax**

```
var options = {
  success: subscribeResponseHandler, 
  complete:  hideProcessing,
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  //url: 'http/localhost:3000/subscription/create'
};

# HERE!
# I dnt know whats exactly callback will be here.
function subscribeResponseHandler(responseText, statusText) {
    window.location.href = 'https://localhost:3000/professional/sign_in'
}

$(form).ajaxSubmit(options)
```

Comment: @Hobowpen r u sure, u have successfully triggering controller ? post yr server console log after submitting the ajax.

Comment: @Hobowpen 
updated my post
`window.location.href = 'https://localhost:3000/professional/sign_in'`

Comment: Now I just get,
SOLR Request (4.3ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  SOLR Request (475.0ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
Completed 200 OK in 2377ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 7.7ms | Solr: 4.3ms)

An nothing more..

Comment: i dnt know why solr. and request 200 should response to ajax form actually.